# how to copy data from mpp file to excel using macro

Tags: excel, ms-project, vba

I am new to macros.I want to write a macro to copy specific data in columns in MPP to another using excel.

I have found a code that will copy data from one excel to another.please help

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopytoPS()
    Dim sfil As String
    Dim owbk As Workbook
    Dim sPath As String

    sPath = "C:\Users\HYMC\Excel\Test\" 'Change the file path for your purposes
    sfil = Dir(sPath & "Management Report PS.xls")

    Range("A2:I22").Copy

    Set owbk = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sfil)
    owbk.Sheets("Sales Data").Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    owbk.Close True 'Save opened workbook and close
    sfil = Dir
End Sub
```

I want to copy certain coloums in MPP to a set of cloumns in Excel.I also want user to just give the destination file path,source file ,source cells to be copied and destination cells

Comment: By mpp file you mean "Microsoft Project file"?

Comment: yes mpp is Microsoft Project Plan file

Comment: @prerna: Yes it is possible to open MPP file in Excel but before I give you the code can you have a look at what Fahim mentioned above?

Comment: yes i have gone through the links

Comment: basically I a have a MPP file at one location and excel at another I dont want to manually copy data from MPP to excel I want to automate it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7908/discussion-between-prerna-and-siddharth-rout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with MPP file in Excel, Open the VBA Editor and click References on the Tools menu. In the Available References list, click to select the Microsoft Project xx.xx Object Library check box. If the Microsoft Project 9.0 Object Library is not listed, click Browse to locate the MsprjXX.olb file, which is in the folder where you have Microsoft Project installed. The default location is C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office. Click OK to close the References dialog box. Then Use this code.

Since you have not mentioned what you want to copy and where exactly, i will give you a very basic code which you can then work on.

```
'~~> Code to open MPP file in Excel
Sub Sample()
    Dim appProj As MSProject.Application
    Dim aProg As MSProject.Project
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    '~~> This is the Sheet Where you want the data to be copied
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set appProj = CreateObject("Msproject.Application")

    '~~> This is a MS Project File. Change path as applicable.
    appProj.FileOpen "C:\MS Project.mpp"

    Set aProg = appProj.ActiveProject

    appProj.Visible = True

    '~~> Now you have the MPP file opened, rest of the code goes here
End Sub
```

> > > prerna: Can u also provide me the tutorial to learn macros to be used in excel.It would be very helpful

You can visit this link which is a good start. But ultimately, it all depends on how much you practice :)

**Topic**: Record and use Excel macros

**Link**: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/record-and-use-excel-macros-HA001054837.aspx

**More On Macros**:

http://www.excel-vba.com/

http://www.excel-vba-easy.com/

http://www.mrexcel.com/articles.shtml

Comment: MPP file is getting opened But How to Copy data from tasks in MPP to excel